# Flutter: Migrating to null safety leads to errors

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, stream-builder

After migrating to null safety:`dataSnapshot.data.docs`; `.docs` is underlined red.
I have tried `dataSnapshot.data?.docs`, `dataSnapshot.data!.docs` but still underlined red is there.

```
   StreamBuilder(
      stream: commentsReference
          .doc(postId)
          .collection("comments")
          .orderBy("timestamp", descending: false)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
          return loader();
        }
      
        List<CommentTile> comments = [];
        dataSnapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc) {//.docs is underlined red
        //tried dataSnapshot.data?.docs, dataSnapshot.data!.docs.

          comments.add(CommentTile.fromDocument(doc));
        });
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: comments),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Do you trying add type cast to `StreamBuilder` yet?

Comment: Can you include the code for the whole widget and also `CommentTile`? So we can add to our IDE and see ther errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have model like this (or must be)

```
class Post {
 //title
 //contents
 List<CommentTile> docs;
}
```

and you have to change this

```
StreamBuilder -> StreamBuilder<Post>
```